# почему перестает работать нажатие виджет если удалить приложение из многозадачности

Tags: java, android, service, виджет, многозадачность

Если удалить приложение из многозадачность, то перестает работать запуск service при нажатии на виджет.
Кто нибудь знает как запускать service, даже если приложение удалено из многозадачности?

```
 package ---.----.----------.----;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
 import android.content.ComponentName;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.widget.RemoteViews;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 public class wdget extends AppWidgetProvider {
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        CharSequence widgetText = onclickwidget.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.wdget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, update.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds)
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) wdgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В манифесте указать в сервисе (пишу по памяти)

```
StopWithTask="false"
```

Comment: Arty Morris не помогло

Comment: Значит остальное неправильно сделали

Comment: Arty Morris например?

Comment: Я не знаю ваш код. У меня в приложении и активити и несколько сервисов и виджеты, и всё работает хорошо, в том числе в фоне